# Delimiter for storing multiple values for a default value of a parameter in rdl Microsoft SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I want to know what delimiter I can use to store multiple values in a database column for a default value of a parameter in rdl. Ideally, the delimiter should be an invalid character in the default value. Thus, when it is processed, it can be identified as a delimiter as opposed to the default value.

Because when a parameter allows multiple values, I need a way to differentiate them when they are stored in to a database table column, and retrieved them for display. E.g. when a date parameter has '2011-01-01' and '2011-02-01' as default values, when it is stored in a database column, I need a delimiter to differentiate it, so that I can retrieve them and populate it back to the drop down list on the rdl for display.

E.g. To create a default values, right click the paramter, on the Report Parameter Properties windows, select Allow multiple values on General tab, and add default value on Defautl Values tab.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I am looking for a list of invalid characters for default values published by Microsoft, similar to invalid characters in file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple default values from a dataset, they should be returned as multiple records, not as one record with a special delimiter.

No matter what delimiter you use, SSRS will treat one returned value as one value for the parameter.

(If you need to store the default somewhere, and are parsing it to create multiple rows in your dataset, then, of course, the choice of delimiter can be whatever you want. A common choice is the pipe (|) character.)

Comment: I am looking for a list of invalid characters for default values published by Microsoft, similar to invalid characters in file name.